# Degradability of unitary channels

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

A quantum channel $\Phi$ is said to be degradable if there is a (generally noisy) map $\Lambda$ that connects $\Phi$ and its complementary map $\Phi_E$ as $$\Phi_E=\Lambda\circ \Phi. $$
The most basic example I can think of for this concept is the unitary mapping $\Phi_{U_S}(\rho_S)=U_S\rho_S U_S^\dagger$. Since the time evolution operator simplifies as $U_{SE}=U_S\otimes 1_E$, in Stinespring representation the action of the complementary map $\Phi_E$ is trivial and gives $\Phi_E(\rho_S)=|0\rangle_E\langle 0|$ for any input $\rho_S$. All the transmitted information is thus found in $\Phi(\rho_S)=\rho_S'$.

My question is actually more of a notational doubt. I have seen the map $\Lambda$ for this case written simply as $\Lambda=|0\rangle_E\langle 0|$. Is this just a shorthand for the more precise $$\Lambda=0_S\otimes |0\rangle_E\langle0|, $$
where (the non-linear operator) $0_S$ acts as $0_S \rho_S=1_S$ for every state $\rho_S$? We would then obtain
$$\Lambda(\Phi(\rho_S))=(0_S\otimes |0\rangle_E\langle 0|)(\rho_S'\otimes 1_E)=1_S\otimes |0\rangle_E\langle 0| $$ and then we can freely ignore the identity $1_S$ to write $\Phi_E(\rho_S)=|0\rangle_E\langle 0|$ as a map $\mathscr S(\mathcal H_S)\to \mathscr S(\mathcal H_E)$.

Am I overcomplicating things? In general, we omit to write the trivial factors of a separable state living in the tensor product of multiple spaces (i.e. $1_S\otimes |0\rangle_E\langle 0|\sim |0\rangle_E\langle 0|$ as above) but we should restore them to avoid mistakes such as writing $$\Lambda(\Phi(\rho_S))=|0\rangle_E\langle 0|\psi'\rangle_S\langle \psi'|$$ which clearly doesn't make sense, as we are trying to multiply things living in different spaces. But my way of doing things also implies thinking (at least temporarily) about the image of the map $\Phi(\rho_S)$ as something that lives in $\mathcal H_S\otimes \mathcal H_E$ rather than simply $\mathcal H_S$ (even though the second factor is trivial and can be forgotten) which also strikes me as imprecise.

So it appears I've overthought myself into a corner. How do I get out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degrading map should act from the space S to the space E (as a CP map).

The correct way to write this map would be
$$
\Lambda(\rho_S) = \mathrm{tr}(\rho_S)\,|0\rangle\langle0|_E\ .
$$

---

(As a side remark, it seems that you are using $1_{S,E}$ either in two different ways, or incorrectly. While in the beginning, where you define $U_{SE}$, it is an identity matrix -- unless you mean $E$ is one-dimensional -- later it only makes sense as a number (i.e. a 1x1 matrix), in which case it makes more sense to just omit it (after all, there is no system $E$ in the output of $\Phi$, and no $S$ in the output of $\Lambda$.)

Comment: Ah, with the trace of $\rho_S$ it now makes sense to me! Hadn't thought of that. Just one question though which arises from your remark: in an expression such as $\rho_{SE}=\rho_S\otimes 1_E$, $1_E$ is the identity, not the number one, right? That's what I meant in the OP. Now I realize it doesn't make sense to write $\rho_S'\otimes 1_E$ in this case because as you mention this should only be a state of $S$.

Comment: @BrownHole Precisely, unless in the latter case $1_E$ is supposed to denote a 1x1 matrix to indicate that the system S is not present (=trivial).